# How to select a particular tab from other page using anchor tag in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, anchor

I wonder if we can select a particular tab in a JQuery tab system from another page..?
For example I have a 3 menu section that is Home, Services, Contact.

In services page I have a tab system with 3 tabs for now (Name1, Name2, Name3). 
For example I am in home page, and in submenu under Services I have links to Tabs (Name1, Name2, Name3 ).

If I click in name2 in submenu I need to display the Name2 tab (default visible one is Name1) in services page.

I have tried to give the it link like this... services.php#tab2 (like anchor tag method)
unfortunately it doesn't work..

I’m using the following JQuery for my tab system...

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(window).load(function(){
            initTabs();
});

function initTabs(){

    var strHash = document.location.hash;

    if (strHash == "") {

    if($j('.tabs').length){
        var $tabsNav = $j('.tabs-nav');
        var $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li');
        $tabsNav.each(function() {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $this.next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide().first().show();
            $this.children('li').first().addClass('active').stop(true,true).show();
        });
         } else

        $("a[href='" + strHash + "']").parent().click();


        $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $this.siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
            $this.parent().next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide().siblings( $this.find('a').attr('href') ).fadeIn();
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    }}
```

tab navigation is like below:

```
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
                <li><a href="#tab-1">name1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">name2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-3">name3</a></li>
     </ul>

<div class="tabs-container">
            <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">TABLE 1</div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">TABLE 2</div>
            <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">TABLE 3</div>
        </div>
```

At home page I have menu options like one bellow, so if someone clicks on menu2 at home page it should redirect him to service page but open the tab2.

```
<nav class="menu-container">
<ul class="menu" id="">
<li id="menu-item" class=""><a class="" href="services.php#tab2" style="line-height: 82px;"><span>Name2</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item" class=""><a class="" href="services.php#tab3" style="line-height: 82px;"><span>Name3</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I hope that someone can answer the above question.

Thanks a lot

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution by checking the hash when the page loads, and then trigger a click.
Here is the whole code, hope it will help someone.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(window).load(function(){
        initTabs();
});

function initTabs(){

    if($j('.tabs').length){
        var $tabsNav = $j('.tabs-nav');
        var $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li');
        $tabsNav.each(function() {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $this.next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide().first().show();
            $this.children('li').first().addClass('active').stop(true,true).show();
        });
        $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
            var $this = $j(this);
            $this.siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
            $this.parent().next().children('.tab-content').stop(true,true).hide().siblings( $this.find('a').attr('href') ).fadeIn();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    var hash = $j.trim( window.location.hash );
    if (hash) $j('.tabs-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click'); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use cookies, store the name of the tab you want to access and use the cookie value to programatically select the tab.